# Has anyone tried datanucleus JPA implementation with orientdb?

Tags: jpa, datanucleus, orientdb

I am trying to implement Datanucleus JPA for orientdb for my java project. I am able to successfully make it work with datanucleus3.1.2, mongodb. but when I tried to do with orientdb, I read it works with 2.x (i guess ONLY 2.x at moment). I replaced all datanucleus 3.x jars with 2.x.

For mongodb I have following works fine

`Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mongodb");`

with persistence.xml

```
    <persistence-unit name="mongodb">
    <properties>
        <property name="datanucleus.ConnectionURL" value="mongodb:localhost:27017/db"/>
        <property name="datanucleus.storeManagerType" value="mongodb" />
        <property name="datanucleus.autoCreateSchema" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Has anyone able to get it work? How to create entity manager factory for orientdb?
How the persistence.xml should look like?

I keep getting 
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named orientdb
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:84)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:54)

Comment: It doesn't work. Rather use the native JPA-like implementation: http://code.google.com/p/orient/wiki/ObjectDatabase

Comment: has anyone working on supporting it for datanucleus version 3?

Comment: its open source, so you could easily get the code for their plugin and update it as per the instructions in the DataNucleus Wiki for moving between versions. No interest from the DataNucleus side to spend our effort on it. Obviously a "JPA-like" interface is not JPA so you´d have to change/recompile your code to use it on other datastores and that may not be an option